# Using StackLayout with Grid pushes my button outside the screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get my button with the text "I am causing problems" at the bottom right side of my page, but it is being pushed out of the screen on my emulator.

I have read the documentation about `StackLayout` and looked up alike questions on StackOverflow and this is the closest I have come... Without success unfortunately.

I have not used any CSS and I would prefer to not use it, if not needed.

[image]

```
<ContentPage>//STANDARD CONTENTPAGE STUFF SUCH AS XMLS TAKEN OUT

<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Priority="0" Order="Primary" Text="{Binding Inter}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1" Margin="10">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Cb}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="5" 
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Text}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" Command="{Binding Command}" HeightRequest="75" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Msg}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="5" 
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <ButtonText="I am causing problems!"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Dom. The problem derives from overcomplicating your xaml/ui. If you were to remove the Grid that contains your button and just replace it with a plain button. You can then style that button to fit as needed in your UI.

If you replace the Grid-with-button with just a button then it automatically becomes a direct child of the StackLayout. Now give the Button a Height of 100 and a HorizontalOptions of End and you will probably get what you were looking for with your button.

I've added an image and the code so it's easy for you to replicate. Thanks for your question and good luck with your programming endeavors.

[image: Postitioning button at bottom right of screen]

And here's your code.

```
<StackLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1" Margin="10">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Cb}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="5" 
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Text}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" 
                            Command="{Binding Command}" 
                            HeightRequest="75" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Msg}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2"
                    VerticalItemSpacing="5" 
                    HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Button Text="test knop met text" HeightRequest="100" 
                HorizontalOptions="End"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: It's almost laughable as how to easy the solution actually was when I read your solution! "Bedankt" for your time and effort!

Comment: I see you spotted my Dutch there in the button text :). I still find myself strangled up in creating overly complex xaml from time to time. It's all part of the learning curve I guess.